# Change recyclerview's layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on catalog product which is showing list of product and user can change the view mode from list to grid and vice versa. I use RecyclerView to show the list. I able to change the layout manager of recyclerview but unable to change the layout of item (xml). Here's my code :

**FragmentListProduct.java**

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    productData = new JSONArray();
    linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(fragmentActivity);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(fragmentActivity, 2);

    lpAdapter = new ListProductAdapter(fragmentActivity, true, productData, null,
            new ListProductAdapter.OnProductClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProductClick(View v, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(fragmentActivity, "id:"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    MainActivity.setIdToRead((int) id);
                    MainActivity.replaceFragment(FragmentListProduct.this, new FragmentViewProduct());
                }
            });
    rvProductList = (RecyclerView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.rvProductList);
    rvProductList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    rvProductList.setAdapter(lpAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.list_mode) {
        if (!listMode) {
            listMode = true;
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.grid);
            rvProductList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            lpAdapter.setListMode(false);
            lpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            listMode = false;
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.list);
            rvProductList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            lpAdapter.setListMode(true);
            lpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**ListProductAdapter.java**

```
@Override
public ListProductHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Log.i("zihad", "onCreateViewHolder()");
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(activity).inflate(listMode ? R.layout.list_product_list : R.layout.list_product_grid, parent, false);
    return new ListProductHolder(v);
}

public void setListMode(boolean listMode) {
    this.listMode = listMode;
}
```

When i scroll the recyclerview, Logcat say "12-08 09:38:09.795 8067-8067/? I/zihad: onCreateViewHolder()" but not change the item's layout. What's wrong with my code, how to solve this?

Comment: The setListMode has no effect on the adapter the as the value of listMode continues to be false. Try resetting the adapter and passing the value of listMode through the constructor instead.

Comment: You can also pass the value and change the layout using a static method. What you are doing is changing the value of listMode of the adapter but the adapter object is already passed and until it isn't supplied again to the recycler, the value of listMode will remain to be false. Hope this helps.

Comment: your previous comment was right, i just add `rvProductList.setAdapter(lpAdapter);`

Comment: Great that the solution helped.

Answer (score 0):

Put `rvProductList.setAdapter(lpAdapter);` into onOptionItemSelected :

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.list_mode) {
        if (!listMode) {
            listMode = true;
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.grid);
            rvProductList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            lpAdapter.setListMode(false);
            lpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            listMode = false;
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.list);
            rvProductList.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
            lpAdapter.setListMode(true);
            lpAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        rvProductList.setAdapter(lpAdapter);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```